# Compare elements in a list and create a new one

Tags: c#

I have a List with Users:

```
List<UserEntry> list1 = new List<UserEntry>();
list1.Add(new UserEntry { login = "1", requestorList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" } });
        list1.Add(new UserEntry { login = "2", requestorList = new List<string>() { "1", "4", "3" } });
        list1.Add(new UserEntry { login = "3", requestorList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" } });
```

I want to find the elements that have same requestorList and group them in a second List. In the above example the first and third element have 1,2,3.

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            var kar = list1.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list1.Count; j++)
            {
            if(kar.requestorList.Equals(list1.ElementAt(j).requestorList))
                {
                    list2.Add(kar);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: The secoond List should have only 2 elements, since the first one and the third have same requestorLists

Comment: Why is it not working? What do you get instead of what you expected?

Comment: all elements from List1 are copied in List2

Comment: All elements are being copied because you are comparing each user to itself in the inner for loop.

Comment: You compare each element to itself included

Comment: You want to group the elements inside the list, or the lists themselves?

Comment: as Yuval Itzchakov said, be more clear about grouping elements plz

Comment: The elements inside the list that have same requestorLists

Comment: Instead of `list1.ElementAt(i)` you can just use `list1[i]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain the List you want, fancy doing this:

First of all, you need to add a second if, like this:

```
if(list1.ElementAt(i).Equals(list1.ElementAt(j))){
    continue;
}
```

in order to skip the cases where you would compare an element to itself.

Also, if you don't want duplicates, use this instead of only doing `list2.Add(kar);` :

```
if(!list2.Contains(kar)){

    list2.Add(kar);
}
```

Edit: The full code should look something like this if i didn't mess up:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            var kar = list1.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list1.Count; j++)
            {
            if(kar.requestorList.SequenceEqual(list1.ElementAt(j).requestorList))
                {
                     if(list1.ElementAt(i).Equals(list1.ElementAt(j))){
                          continue;
                     }

                     if(!list2.Contains(kar)){

                         list2.Add(kar);
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code but now the second List doesn't contain any elements.

Comment: Checking equality of lists does not check them element by element. Use SequenceEqual instead of Equals.

Comment: I didn't know that as well. Hope I edited it right. Sadly I can't test it right now but at least that code is what I would come up with right now

Answer (score 1):

This is your code with a slight difference

```
   for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            var kar = list1.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = i+1; j < list1.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(kar.requestorList.OrderBy(t => t), list1.ElementAt(j).requestorList.OrderBy(t => t)))
                {
                    list2.Add(kar);
                    list2.Add(list1.ElementAt(j));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code:

- You can use indexer to access the element from the list instead of ElementAt() which is more verbal. It looks cleaner to me
- Equals() only compares reference of your list, not the content. So ["1", "2", "3"] and ["1", "3", "2"] will give false
- And the other thing is you compare element in list1 with itself like other answers mention

Here's my attempt using LINQ:

```
    var list2 = list1.GroupBy(e => 
                    e.requestorList.OrderBy(r => r)       //Order list ascending
                                   .Aggregate((i, j) => i + j))    //Append elements in the list together to create "signature" of the list
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)          //Select grouping that has at least 2 elements
                    .SelectMany(g => g);         //Flatten all the lists into single list
```

I use OrderBy() and Aggregate() to create kind of "signature" for your requestorList, so that ["1", "3", "2"] and ["1", "2", "3"] having the same signature "123", then group the elements by that signature

Not sure what you expect in the list2, so I just flatten everything that have duplicate requestorList into single list

Comment: First order might be important, though it's not obvious from the example.  Second instead of `Aggregate` it would be better to use `string.Join` and you'd want to use a delimiter so that ["1", "2"] isn't equal to ["12"]